# SSL certificate error net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: ssl, openssl

I've got an issue with my local SSL certificate in that the site isn't downloading the CSS and JS files because of the error `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`.  I found that it was originally using an SHA-1 certificate and that could be the problem.  In order to fix this I ran this command:

`sudo openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt`

When I look at the certificate details on Chrome (v48) under "Certificate Signature Algorithm" it says "PKCS #1 SHA-256 with RSA Encryption"

I'm still getting the same issue, it doesn't appear to be a caching issue as I've appended a timestamp to the url so that its not cached.

I'm not sure what else I need to do to resolve this.  Anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: So your generating your own certificate? It will not be trusted by default, you need to search for *trust self signed certificate on xxx* where xxx is your OS/distro (on any machine you want to access the site)